# RSACryptoServiceProvider export Public and Private key pairs (powershell)

Tags: powershell, encryption, rsa

I need to write a script which encrpyts a text on **client side** and then it sends the encrypted text to my **backend**. I need both in **base64** encode.

The only way I found to get what I need is to create a **RSACryptoServiceProvider** and get its private parameters with **ExportParameters(true)**

```
$cryptoService = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
$params = $cryptoService.ExportParameters(1);
Write-Output $params;

Output:
  Exponent : {1, 0, 1}
  Modulus  : {235, 109, 139, 92...} 
  P        : {236, 204, 53, 183...} 
  Q        : {254, 132, 230, 6...}  
  DP       : {48, 134, 112, 131...} 
  DQ       : {183, 178, 169, 230...}
  InverseQ : {199, 175, 213, 220...}
  D        : {227, 52, 133, 26...}
```

How am I supposed to combine them in order to get the **Private** and **Public** keys pair?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Your first and second sentences don't seem to be related. Retrieving parameters does not encrypt data. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I think the parameters, combined in some way, give the keys pair. Am I wrong?
How am I supposed to comine them to get them?
Or is there another way to get the private and public key of a RSACryptoServiceProvider object?

Comment: I know how to encrypt data, yet I need a way to create a pair of keys and use them. The generated private key in backend, and the public key in client. However it s more difficult then I thought to retrieve such a keys pair. The RSACryptoServiceProvider does everything under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to generate a new random RSACryptoServiceProvider object. It will creates the keys you need.

After that you can call the **ExportCspBlob(false)** to get the public key and **ExportCspBlob(true)** to get both pair of keys.

Finally, on backend you need to **ImportCspBlob** with the result of the previous **ExportCspBlob(true)** call, whereas on client you need to **ImportCspBlob** with the **ExportCspBlob(false)** result